# c# 6 string interpolation in earlier c# versions

Tags: c#, string-formatting, c#-6.0

I like what I see with the c# 6.0 string interpolation feature, and it's something I've wanted for a long time. My problem is, I own visual studio 2013 and don't feel like upgrading to 2015 yet. I looked into whether one can run 6.0 in vs2013 and it doesn't look like this will be possible, so now my question is: could I export just this string interpolation feature from 6 and run it as a library in my earlier versions somehow? I'd like to start using this feature now if possible, and have it remain forward compatible with 6.0 later when I finally do upgrade.

-- update --
Since the exact language feature cannot be implemented, could a variation be used that would still be syntactically correct in earlier c#'s, but would allow the same token names in the string like 6 uses? This would allow easier upgrades later, and also allow using real token names now instead of in numeric placeholders.

Comment: Since this is a C# 6 language feature, it shouldn't compile under c# 5 and lower. However, you could run a pre-build script to convert `$"{typeof(string).Name}"` to `String.Format("{0}", typeof(string).Name);` in your source code files. If you are writing code in VS, though, you're still going to get that red squiggle under each use of the dollar string.

Comment: There are a lot of cool features in C# 6 so better upgrade

Comment: VS 2015 Community Edition is free.

Comment: There are a lot of very important (and cool) features in VS 2015 too - like the liver performance profiler.

Answer (score 1):

A library can't change the syntax of the language.

You might be able to force VS to use the new compiler, but you can't change the IDE itself. This means that features like syntax highlighting, IntelliSense and debugging wouldn't work for your code. Because of that, I don't think attempting to do this is worth it.

Comment: MS did this with Bcl.Async but that was a very important feature that was worth investing into.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Bcl.Async gives you a way to use new features in new VS (and thus new compiler), but using old framework. This question asks about how to use new features in old VS.

Comment: Bcl.Async does *not* require a new compiler, it works with VS 2012 and above. I've used them to add `async` support to .NET 4.0 projects in both 2012 and 2013. It's the combination of Bcl.Build and Async that *deploy* a new (pre)compiler. If MS thought string interpolation was as important they could release it in the same way. Not worth it IMHO, and 2015 does have a full-featured free edition

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos For async-await, VS2012 *is* the new compiler (you don't need Bcl.Async to use async-await if you're targeting .Net 4.5 using VS2012). Bcl.Async doesn't deploy a new compiler (and there's certainly no precompiler for async).

Comment: VS 2012 Compiler modifications are deployed by the Bcl.Build package, an indirect dependency of Bcl.Async. Without it, you wouldn't be able to use async/await in .NET 4 projects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That package seems to be all about references and binding redirects, I don't see anything compiler-related in it.